# ubuntu ldapsetpasswd set password not working

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-12.04

becase I installed a ldap server, I am making a server client authentication for server users but having problem with password thing. if I put a password in add ldif file and put some encoding tag in front of the password like {crypt}somepassword and add it to ldap as new user it works. but if I try to change password with the commands ldappasswd it says

```
ldappasswd user
SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
Please enter your password:
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database
```

if I try with -x parameter then says

```
ldappasswd user -x
Result: Strong(er) authentication required (8)
Additional info: only authenticated users may change passwords
```

and ldapsetpasswd changing password but password does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your ldap server is offering SASL methods it probably shouldn't.

If you want to simple bind (`-x`) instead of using SASL you should also use `-ZZ` to require `STARTTLS`. Simple binds also require that the `dn` is specified with `-D` and the password with either `-w <password>` or `-W`, which will generate a prompt.

However, you should edit whatever Ubuntu's equivlent of `/etc/sasl2/slapd.conf` to exclude SASL methods you don't support.

```
mech_list: external plain
```

Also: You should really glue password changing in with `pam-ldap` so that users can change their passwords with `passwd`.

Side Note: {crypt} is probably inadvisable. If you want to store credentials directly in LDAP you should probably use {SSHA}